# Getting error for artisan commands ( In routes-v7.php Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state() )

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have upgraded Laravel version from 5.7 to 8.34. I'm getting this error for all artisan commands.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's an error in `routes-v7.php`, so look there for the code to track it down.

Comment: @aynber Yes, Actually I used "locate" command to locate this file. It was present in /bootstrap/cache/routes-v7.php. I have deleted the file from cache it's working fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To others: removing the routes-v7 might help, but it's possibly caused due to a `return` in your routes file (`web.php`). Remove it and use a controller to return a specific view/back() etc.

Answer (score 1):

@Tjab answer is the correct one. Just a few more thoughts:

It's because you're using Closures (a.k.a. Lambda functions `function () use() {}`) in your configuration. I'm pretty sure it's because you're using [HTTP redirect routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects). **DON'T USE THAT FEATURE**, since you won't be able to cache your routes, which is actually a good idea because it should increase your application speed. Otherwise your config can't be serialized (what caching actually means) to disk.

**Instead create controller and action for each redirect.**

Also check your configuration files for Closures and remove them (same for all other PHP frameworks).

Answer (score 1):

**Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state()**

In my case, I delete the **bootstrap/cache/config.php** file and run the **PHP artisan vendor: publish** but the same error occurs in the terminal.

Solution:-

1 Delete the routes-v7.php under the bootstrap folder path(**bootstrap/cache/routes-v7.php**) .

2 Run the PHP artisan optimize Command. then they recreate the deleted file in the repository.

Laravel 8 && Laravel 9

**Please Support !!!!**
https://stackoverflow.com/users/16749364/hitesh-sharma